# how to solve iis error 500 upload file using php

Tags: php, file, post

I am trying to upload a file to an IIS based server. here is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
//ini_set('error_log','/httpdocs/error_log');
echo "upload_max_filesize: " . ini_get ("upload_max_filesize"). "<br>";
echo "post_max_size: " . ini_get ("post_max_size"). "<br>";
echo "memory_limit: " . ini_get ("memory_limit"). "<br>";
echo "max_file_uploads: " . ini_get ("max_file_uploads"). "<br>";
echo "max_execution_time: " . ini_get ("max_execution_time"). "<br>";
echo "max_input_time: " . ini_get ("max_input_time"). "<br>";
echo "file_uploads: " . ini_get ("file_uploads"). "<br>";
echo "default_socket_timeout: " . ini_get ("default_socket_timeout"). "<br>";
echo "<br>";
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>
<html>
<body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I used to get this error when i try to upload a file greater than 13MB:

> Server Error
>
> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

then i added the error_reporting and i got this:

> Network Error (tcp_error)
>
> A communication error occurred: "Can't send more" The Web Server may
>   be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from
>   responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
>
> For assistance, contact your network support team.

this is the settings:

> upload_max_filesize: 20M
>
> post_max_size: 128M
>
> memory_limit: -1
>
> max_file_uploads: 20
>
> max_execution_time: 50000
>
> max_input_time: 50000
>
> file_uploads: on
>
> default_socket_timeout: 6000

this is the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\vx.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <!--
    <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
            <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>  
-->
  <appSettings />
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime 
        executionTimeout="9000" 
        maxRequestLength="65536" 
        useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" 
        minFreeThreads="8" 
        minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" 
        appRequestQueueLimit="1000" 
        enableVersionHeader="true" 
    />
    <customErrors mode="On" />
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </httpModules>
    <sessionState timeout="2880" />
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5" />
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
      </compiler>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5" />
        <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true" />
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
           <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
      <remove name="ScriptResource" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I accessed the server remotely and tested it the response was:

> PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 9202605 bytes exceeds the limit
>   of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: just a thought, if you are running it behind a proxy server (usually in office LANs), it may prevent file upload above certain size.

Comment: no i tried it from an outside network

Comment: you should limit the post size to 8 m which is the default limit or increase in ini

Comment: post_max_size is: 128M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I changed the PHP settings from the cPanel, and whenever I used `ini_get()` it gave me the settings that I had in the cPanel it didn't work.

I solved it (if you can access the `php.ini` file), by changing the setting from the php.ini file itself instead of the cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I recall this is not an issue with php directly but rather with IIS.
You could try adding this into a web.config file and adding it to your php projects web server root directory.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
           <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the file upload error is related to file size. You should dump the $_FILE and check the error code against the codes listed here, [link](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)
You could also confirm that the above snippet is ok for your version of IIS

Answer (score 1):

The Issue:
Certain php files are causing an "HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error" when running Windows Server 2008 and IIS as a web server.

The Fix:
We have found that simple php notices (ie. variable not defined) are sent to stderr by using the FastCGI protocol and cause the IIS FastCGI module to fail the request and display an HTTP 500 error. Disabling FastCGI logging will prevent PHP from sending error information over stderr, and generating 500 response codes for the client.

To fix this, make sure that the following setting is set to 0 in your php.ini file:

```
fastcgi.logging=0
```

More information on FastCGI and PHP on IIS can be found here:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-70/

Source : http://www.redcart.com/forums/showthread.php?t=377